# SetLayeredWindowAttributes not working on Windows 8+ (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm writing a library that makes a color in the window client area invisible.

In the application half, first I call window_fix_transparent_color() to make the window layered. Then I use window_set_transparent_color() to make a color in the client area invisible.

Here's my library's code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <windows.h>

extern "C"
{
    void window_fix_transparent_color(double window_handle)
    {
        // sets the window flags to support RGB color transparency.
        SetWindowLong((HWND)(DWORD)window_handle,GWL_EXSTYLE,
            GetWindowLong((HWND)(DWORD)window_handle,GWL_EXSTYLE)|WS_EX_LAYERED);
    }

    void window_set_transparent_color(double window_handle,double red,double green,double blue)
    {
        // sets the RGB color to be transparent for the specified window.
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes((HWND)(DWORD)window_handle,RGB(red,green,blue),255,LWA_COLORKEY);
    }
}
```

I'm using the version of MinGW that is packaged with the latest Code::Blocks as my compiler. It works on Windows 7, but not on Windows 8, 8.1, or 10...

Any ideas as to why that is? Also, a weird thing worth noting - it used to work on Windows 8/8.1/10, which leads me to believe a certain Windows update for those platforms may have broken my code. I haven't made any changes to my code since the time it stopped working on platforms past Windows 7.

Thanks!

Comment: A GUI library like Winforms executes [this code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,2895b1373643ef53) when a form's Opacity or TransparencyKey property is changed.  Note the call to SetWindowPos().

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure I understand what your point is.

Comment: You tagged the question with c++ and then put all the code in extern "C", rather strange if you ask me...

Comment: @Anders I selected a C++ project, and that extern "C" was what Code::Blocks gave birth to. Don't ask me why...

Comment: **Why are you passing the window handles around as something of type `double` ???**

Comment: @selbie because the software I am writing a plugin for does not accept hwnd

Comment: If you are writing for something specific with weird requirements then you should say so somewhere in your question! The ABI must support a pointer sized integer type, otherwise you cannot even pass a pointer around.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using strange types and casts? You should never cast a handle type to `DWORD`, use `INT_PTR` or `UINT_PTR` if you must. A `double` is actually larger than a `HWND` in 32-bit applications so you are actually wasting space in addition to making things harder for yourself. A `double` cannot be used to store a handle in a 64-bit application!

You are also not checking the return value of `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` so it is impossible to know what the problem really is.

Rewrite the function with correct types and error handling:

```
void display_error(DWORD error)
{
    char buf[100];
    wsprintfA(buf, "Error %u!", error);
    MessageBoxA(NULL, buf, 0, 0); // Ideally you would pass a window handle here but I don't know if your handle is actually valid
}

void window_fix_transparent_color(HWND window_handle)
{
    DWORD error;

    // get the window flags to see if RGB color transparency is supported.
    SetLastError(0);
    LONG_PTR ExStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(window_handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    if (ExStyle == 0)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        if (error != 0)
        {
            display_error(error);
            return;
        }
    }

    if ((ExStyle & WS_EX_LAYERED) == 0)
    {
        // set the window flags to support RGB color transparency.
        SetLastError(0);
        if (!SetWindowLongPtr(window_handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyle | WS_EX_LAYERED))
        {
            error = GetLastError();
            if (error != 0)
                display_error(error);
        }
    }
}

void window_set_transparent_color(HWND window_handle, BYTE red, BYTE green, BYTE blue)
{
    // sets the RGB color to be transparent for the specified window.
    if (!SetLayeredWindowAttributes(window_handle, RGB(red, green, blue), 255, LWA_COLORKEY))
    {
        display_error(GetLastError());
    }
}

...

HWND mywindow = CreateWindowEx(...);
window_fix_transparent_color(mywindow);
window_set_transparent_color(mywindow, ...);
```

Comment: SetLayeredWindowAttributes returns true even though the color isn't made transparent on windows 8+. As previously stated, on windows 7 it works.

Comment: `HWND`s never use the upper half of their range. It is safe (even if confusing) to store a window handle in a `double`. See [Interprocess Communication Between 32-bit and 64-bit Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384203.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're using "basic" or "classic" theme on Windows 7. Although
undocumented, it activates Windows XP compatibility mode for the Desktop Window
Manager, and changes the way layered windows work. That doesn't happen in later
versions of Windows.

Comment: I actually found out recently that my code is also working on some Windows 10 computers. It's really weird and makes little sense to me. Some Windows 10 computers it works and others it doesn't. I was going to accept your answer because it sounded promising, but then I found this out. :(